# how can i show multiple charts in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Similar questions have been asked before, and one answer suggests using

```
df.plot(ax=ax)
```

But I do not understand how I can use that in my example below. All the answers I have read give plain charts with simple plots. I cannot figure out via the documentation, or via any of the answers how to get the following to work, please help with my problem, I have been trying for over a day now. Please do not mark it as a dupe. Thanks.

I can produce charts with the following for loop. The charts have the axis date and runtime_mins. The issue im facing is that jupyter outputs these one chart per line. I would like to have them smaller, and print many per line.

```
x = 1

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
for step in uniqueSteps:
    temp_data_frame = df[df['step'].str.contains(step)]
    ax = temp_data_frame[['date', 'runtime_mins']].plot(x='date', y='runtime_mins', kind='bar', title=step, figsize=(5, 3), legend=True, fontsize=12)
    ax.set_xlabel("date", fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel("mins", fontsize=12)
    x = x + 1
```

The above produces the correct charts, but in a vertical stack, with one chart per line.

I can also produce the charts in the size I would like, stacking with many per line like this:

```
x = 1
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
for step in uniqueSteps:
    sub = fig.add_subplot(4, 6, x)
    x = x + 1
```

What I cannot do, is get the chart that I have plotted in the first part above, in to the figure / subplots I have display above in the second code sample.

below is my current output[image]

*note, there are many coloured charts that show, stacked vertically, I only showed one in the uploaded image to save space*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really hard to understand what is preventing you to use the solution `df.plot(ax=ax)` in your case. You just have to type it in.

```
x = 1

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
for step in uniqueSteps:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 6, x)
    temp_data_frame = df[df['step'].str.contains(step)]
    temp_data_frame[['date', 'runtime_mins']].plot(x='date', y='runtime_mins', 
                                   kind='bar', title=step, legend=True, fontsize=12, ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel("date", fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel("mins", fontsize=12)
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: thanks very much for answering. I just couldnt get the relationship between plot, axis, figure as they all seem to be able to produce charts.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create the chart using ax.bar as follows:

```
for step in uniqueSteps:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(6, 4, x)
    ax.set_title(step, fontsize='large')
    ax.set_ylabel("mins", fontsize=12)
    temp_data_frame = df[df['step'].str.contains(step)]
    li = range(len(temp_data_frame['date'].tolist()))
    ax.bar(li, temp_data_frame['runtime_mins'], 0.35)
    x = x + 1

plt.show()
```

but ImportanceOfBeingErnest' answer is much better..